# How to fix Unity locked disabled settings?

Tags: 14.04, unity, settings

I am not able to adjust any of the settings in Ubuntu 14.04. Everything in Unity is locked/disabled. I've tried uninstalling Unity and reinstalling it. I've tried installing xscreensaver and that did not work. The PC would suspend and then lock after 5 minutes.

Then I tried opening unity from the terminal and when trying to change the lock settings this showed up... I have no idea what this means but maybe someone a little more knowledgeable can discern what it says and hopefully help me fix the problem?

```
(unity-control-center:4202): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf:
GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code17: 
Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header
```

Comment: welcome to askubuntu! my best guess is the dconf database is corrupt based on "Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header".. Based on some info I found here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/reset-unity-and-compiz-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/ I did some digging and found a file called user in ~./config/dconf which appears to be the dconf configuration file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that your `~/.config/dconf/user*` files are corrupted. Try the following command, it should recreate a new one and allow you to store your settings persistently:

```
mv ~/.config/dconf/ ~/.config/dconf.bak
```

Note that you may loose some customization that you may have set on your system as all of them will be reset.

If it does not solve your problem all you have to do is:

```
mv ~/.config/dconf.bak ~/.config/dconf/
```