# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Dock Customization is not working

Tags: 18.04, launcher, customization, dock

I had cloned my hard disk which has Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to a new hard disk using

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=blocksize`

command. Everything works fine with the cloned hard disk. I can boot the system using cloned hard disk to Ubuntu. However, there is one problem. My desktop customization for gnome is no longer honored. In my original hard disk, I had different wallpaper, taskbar/launcher was on the bottom. In the ubuntu booted from cloned hard disk, I can only see the default desktop appearance. I cannot pin a new app to the launcher/taskbar and it is on the left side which is by default. It seems something is read-only and I cannot understand what. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Update: I just found out that in my nautilus, Ctrl-H to show hidden files and folders is also not working.

Comment: `ls -ailh /home/current_user` Who's owner and what kind of permissions there?

Comment: Hi, my current use is `ivroy` and `ls -ailh /home/ivory` gives following output:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XmcCBWF9AQvU564kCqKaqSI63_wKLIbR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Everything seems as it should be... But what about df -h on both hard disks? I see in your `dd` command not disks, but two partitions of the same `sda` disk. What is more correct?

Comment: `df -h` provides following output:

```
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev

tmpfs           6.3G  2.5M  6.3G   1% /run

/dev/sda4       1.8T  499G  1.2T  30% /
tmpfs            32G  297M   32G   1% /dev/shm

tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock

tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      8.7M  8.7M     0 100% /snap/canoni
```

My disk has 4 partitions. Partition 1: Microsoft reserved 134 MB, Partition 2 Swap 64 GB, Partition 3 EFI System, Parition 4: 1.9 TB, Linux filsystem Ext4.

Comment: For my command in the question, I made a mistake in typing. I am correcting that.

Comment: Update: I just found out that in my nautilus, Ctrl-H to show hidden files and folders is also not working. Neither any customization to `gedit` is being applied.

Comment: Try to create new user, log in as it and check if required features are working.

Comment: @Gryu, I created a new user. In the newly created user, everything works as it should be. I was able to change the wallpaper, and location of the taskbar/launch to the bottom from its default left position. So, what is happening here? Did you get any idea on how to fix things with my current use 'ivory' ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103916/discussion-between-saturns-star-and-gryu).

Answer (score 0):

@Gryu and I had a discussion about what could wrong with this. We tried several things. However, what fixed was accepted answer from [How to fix Unity locked disabled settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534135/how-to-fix-unity-locked-disabled-settings) even though Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't have Unity.

I typed the command:

`mv ~/.config/dconf/ ~/.config/dconf.bak`

and all the lock were disabled upon reboot, I was able to change the background, change the location of the taskbar, etc.

I investigated on what had happened in the midst of this problem. It looks cloning the disk copies everything bit by bit but user id is changed.

These three questions helped me: [How to migrate user settings and data to new machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25633/how-to-migrate-user-settings-and-data-to-new-machine)

[Problem after cloning disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768612/problem-after-cloning-disk)

[How to fix Unity locked disabled settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534135/how-to-fix-unity-locked-disabled-settings)

I also later tried to diff backed up dconf and newly generated one after rebooting, and it looks like this:

[image]

It means something may have remained from the original disk which may have caused some kind of checksum to fail (not sure about technical details here). I hope this helps others as well.