# Ubuntu Power options, Dim screen functions from Gnome unchangeable

Tags: screen, screensaver

After installing ubuntu everything was working fine i disabled Dim screen option, switched of automatica screen lock. All was good however after a bad shutdown i had to recover. After recovery all the options related to to dimming and screen lock options are unchangeable. When i try to press automatic screeen lock to off it jumps back to on button.

Using Ubuntu 18.04 Lts
Any solution?

Comment: Please click [edit] and tell us which version of Linux was installed (Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Core, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu MATE, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, et al.) and the release number.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx everyone who tried to answer i was able to solve the issue.
If anyone is having that issue please have a loot at this link:

[How to fix Unity locked disabled settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534135/how-to-fix-unity-locked-disabled-settings)